# Read data from sharepoint site to another site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to read data FROM the sharepoint on another site? Like make a web call to get data out of your sharepoint?
I’m looking more for a way to make a REST call or web call to the sharepoint data from another site.

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint offers CSOM API, can be used in .net application to read/write or any other operastion in sharepoint.
[look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx)

sharepoint also offers REST API to do similar things.
[look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx)